# Azure AD "groups" claim not being passed to mod_auth_openidc

Tags: azure, apache, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, mod-auth-openidc

I created an Azure AD account to test SSO. I was able to get Apache to authenticate a site using SSO and pass the authenticated user's email address as a header. I'm having trouble getting the "groups" claim to be passed through.

My Apache config looks as follows:

```
LoadModule auth_openidc_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_auth_openidc.so

<IfModule mod_auth_openidc.c>
    OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://sts.windows.net/<removed>/.well-known/openid-configuration

    OIDCClientID <removed>
    OIDCClientSecret <removed>

    OIDCRedirectURI https://<removed>/redirect_uri
    OIDCResponseType code

    OIDCScope "openid email profile groups family_name given_name"
    OIDCSSLValidateServer Off

    OIDCCryptoPassphrase <removed>

    OIDCPassClaimsAs headers
    OIDCClaimPrefix USERINFO_

    OIDCRemoteUserClaim email
    OIDCPassUserInfoAs claims
    OIDCAuthNHeader USER

    OIDCPassIDTokenAs claims
    OIDCPassRefreshToken On
</IfModule>
```

My Optional claims in Azure AD looks like this:

[image]

Additionally I created a group in AD called "Users" and added myself to that group. So I would expect to see "Users" passed as some sort of attribute in the headers.

If I print the HTTP headers on the server I see this...

```
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/httpd/cgi-bin/
CONTEXT_PREFIX: /cgi-bin/
DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/SP/httpd/htdocs/docs
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0
HTTP_COOKIE: _ga=GA1.2.601634409.1596125029; mod_auth_openidc_session=c186c9d6-eebe-11ea-8429-7982f43b32a7
HTTP_HOST: <removed>
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST: document
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE: navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE: none
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER: ?1
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: 1
HTTP_USER: <removed>
HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
HTTP_X_AMZN_TRACE_ID: Root=1-5f52559a-6b8b464ec338a6097565fce0
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: <removed>
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT: 443
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO: https
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/apache-2.4/lib64
PATH: /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
QUERY_STRING:
REMOTE_ADDR: <removed>
REMOTE_PORT: 45364
REMOTE_USER: <removed>
REQUEST_METHOD: GET
REQUEST_SCHEME: http
REQUEST_URI: /cgi-bin/headers.cgi
SCRIPT_FILENAME: /var/httpd/cgi-bin/headers.cgi
SCRIPT_NAME: /cgi-bin/headers.cgi
SCRIPT_URI: http://<removed>/cgi-bin/headers.cgi
SCRIPT_URL: /cgi-bin/headers.cgi
SERVER_ADDR: <removed>
SERVER_ADMIN: <removed>
SERVER_NAME: <removed>
SERVER_PORT: 80
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SIGNATURE:
SERVER_SOFTWARE: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1c
X_REMOTE_USER: <removed>
```

The REMOTE_USER, X_REMOTE_USER and HTTP_USER all show the correct authenticated user email.

I don't see anything related to "groups", "USERINFO_", "family_name", "given_name". Not even blank placeholders.

I'm a bit stuck as the Apache config looks okay as far as I can tell and from what I have read the Azure configuration is okay as well.

Any ideas why the claims are not being passed through?

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
OIDCPassClaimsAs headers
```

to:

```
OIDCPassClaimsAs both
```

... and it worked!